# jQuery problema con punto separador de miles en ordenación de números

Tags: jquery

Dado el siguiente código jQuery para ordenar filas de una tabla, los números con punto para separar miles no se ordenan correctamente.

Los siguientes números :25.000, 1.000, 2.500, 4.000, 850,50, se ordenan como: 850,50, 25.000, 4.000, 2.500, 1.000.

Lo correcto sería que la ordenación final quedara cómo: 25.000, 4.000, 2.500, 1.000, 850,50.

Necesito poder ordenar los números del ejemplo sin eliminar el punto separador de miles y la coma que delimita decimales (ej: 850,50).

El código jQuery:

```
$('th').each(function (column) {
    $(this).addClass('sortable').click(function () {
        var findSortKey = function ($cell) {
            return $cell.find('.sort-key').text().toUpperCase()+ ' ' + $cell.text().toUpperCase();

        };
        var sortDirection = $(this).is('.sorted-asc') ? -1 : 1;
        var $rows = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('tbody tr').get();
        var bob = 0;
        // Loop thorugh all records and find
        $.each($rows, function (index, row) {
            row.sortKey = findSortKey($(row).children('td').eq(column));
        });

        // Compare and sort the rows alphabetically or numerically
        $rows.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a.sortKey.indexOf('-') == -1 && (!isNaN(a.sortKey) && !isNaN(a.sortKey))) {
                 // Rough Numeracy check

                    if (parseInt(a.sortKey) < parseInt(b.sortKey)) {
                        return -sortDirection;
                    }
                    if (parseInt(a.sortKey) > parseInt(b.sortKey)) {
                        return sortDirection;
                    }

            } else {
                if (a.sortKey < b.sortKey) {
                    return -sortDirection;
                }
                if (a.sortKey > b.sortKey) {
                    return sortDirection;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        });

        // Add the rows in the correct order to the bottom of the table
        $.each($rows, function (index, row) {
            $('tbody').append(row);
            row.sortKey = null;
        });

        // Identify the collumn sort order
        $('th').removeClass('sorted-asc sorted-desc');
        var $sortHead = $('th').filter(':nth-child(' + (column + 1) + ')');
        sortDirection == 1 ? $sortHead.addClass('sorted-asc') : $sortHead.addClass('sorted-desc');

        // Identify the collum to be sorted by
        $('td').removeClass('sorted').filter(':nth-child(' + (column + 1) + ')').addClass('sorted');
    });
});
```

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a SO en español. Has de [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/36623/edit) tu pregunta para dejarla en español o será cerrada. Si deseas hacerla en inglés, ha de ser en el sitio https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Error mío, me cambio el site al entrar al editar la respuesta y no me dí cuenta.

Comment: Sin problemas, ya he retirado mi voto de cierre. Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una modificación simple seria:

> Remover el separador de miles (`.`) y reemplazar el separador decimal (`,`) antes de hacer la comparación numérica.

**Nota:** Para indicar el tipo de orden a aplicarse, he agregado un `data attribute` (eg: `data-sort-type="numeric"`) solo en la columna que deseo ordenar de forma numérica.

Entonces, podría quedar algo así:

```js
// Objeto global de configuración numérica
var globalNumberConfig = {
  decimalSeparator: ',',
  thousandSeparator: '.'
};

$('th').each(function (column) {
    $(this).addClass('sortable').click(function () {
        var findSortKey = function ($cell) {
            return $cell.find('.sort-key').text().toUpperCase()+ ' ' + $cell.text().toUpperCase();

        };
        var $columnCell = $(this);
        var sortDirection = $columnCell.is('.sorted-asc') ? -1 : 1;
        var $rows = $columnCell.closest('table').find('tbody tr').get();
        var bob = 0;
        //------------------------
        // CHANGES HERE!
        var thousandSepRE = new RegExp('\\'+globalNumberConfig.thousandSeparator, 'g');
        var decimalSep = globalNumberConfig.decimalSeparator;
        var sortType = $columnCell.data('sortType') || 'text';
        //------------------------

        // Loop thorugh all records and find
        $.each($rows, function (index, row) {
            row.sortKey = findSortKey($(row).children('td').eq(column));
        });

        // Compare and sort the rows alphabetically or numerically
        $rows.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (sortType === 'numeric' ) {
                    //------------------------
                    // CHANGES HERE!
                    // Get acutal numerical value by repalcing thousand and decimal separators
                    var aValue = parseFloat(a.sortKey.replace(thousandSepRE, '').replace(decimalSep, '.')) || 0;
                    var bValue = parseFloat(b.sortKey.replace(thousandSepRE, '').replace(decimalSep, '.')) || 0;

                    // Rough Numeracy check
                    if (aValue < bValue) {
                        return -sortDirection;
                    }
                    if (aValue > bValue) {
                        return sortDirection;
                    }
                    //------------------------

            } else {
                if (a.sortKey < b.sortKey) {
                    return -sortDirection;
                }
                if (a.sortKey > b.sortKey) {
                    return sortDirection;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        });

        // Add the rows in the correct order to the bottom of the table
        $.each($rows, function (index, row) {
            $('tbody').append(row);
            row.sortKey = null;
        });

        // Identify the collumn sort order
        $('th').removeClass('sorted-asc sorted-desc');
        var $sortHead = $('th').filter(':nth-child(' + (column + 1) + ')');
        sortDirection == 1 ? $sortHead.addClass('sorted-asc') : $sortHead.addClass('sorted-desc');

        // Identify the collum to be sorted by
        $('td').removeClass('sorted').filter(':nth-child(' + (column + 1) + ')').addClass('sorted');
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table class="table">
    <caption>Optional table caption.</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th data-sort-type="numeric">$</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td scope="row">A</td>
            <td>0 €</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td scope="row">B</td>
            <td>-5.025 €</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td scope="row">C</td>
            <td>11.789 €</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td scope="row">D</td>
            <td>7.766 €</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td scope="row">E</td>
            <td>5.295 €</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td scope="row">F</td>
            <td>14.861 €</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Correcto. Pero -atención- si los numeros pueden llegar a tener (ademas del punto como separador de miles) tambien una coma como separador decimal, entonces esto no sería suficiente.

Comment: @user3472675, si fuera necesario, el separador de miles y decimal se podrían indicar como un `data attribute` de la columna o de la tabla o como una configuración `global` del sistema. Avisa y añado esta funcionalidad a mi código.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo genial! Funciona como esperaba. Estaría bien conocer como indicar el data attribute de la columna. Gracias!

Comment: @MarcosGallardo, veo que los números que son 29,500 por ejemplo, los ordena después del resto, es decir, no hace el replace del . cuándo tiene dos dígitos.

Comment: @user3472675, por favor, [edita](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/36623/edit) tu pregunta indicando cual es el separador de miles y el decimal; y como te gustaría que esta configuración sea tomada por tu función.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo Editado incluyendo decenas de miles (también estaría bien contemplar centenas) y decimales.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo ahora es perfecto, sólo veo que si el número es 0 o negativo, lo ordena en primer lugar.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo si ordeno de mayor a menor, quedaría así, cómo ejemplo: 0, -5, 25.000, 10.000, 5.500,50

Comment: @MarcosGallardo, mira como queda ahora la ordenación:                              0 €
8.919 €
7.766 €
7.278 €
6.710 €
5.807 €
5.295 €
4.829 €
3.045 €
2.976 €
2.280 €
16.996 €
14.861 €
14.144 €
11.789 €
0 €
-5.025 €

Comment: @user3472675, como programar a ciegas es bastante difícil, he actualizado mi respuesta agregando un snippet funcional.

Comment: Perfecto @MarcosGallardo! :)